# Show map of gmap in a ajax response

Tags: ajax

if i want to display a map using gmap..wich is given by an ajax response..how i have to do that?
Currently, i do that in that way (index.php):

```
<div id="content"></div> <!-- The container of ajax response -->
```

Then the ajax response (show_map.php):

```
<div id="map" align="center" style="width:100%; height:300px;"></div>
    <script>
        function locate()
            {
                new GMaps({
                div: '#map',
                lat: <?php echo $dati['latitude'];?>,
                zoom: 17,
                lng: <?php echo $dati['longitude'];?>
                });
            }
            locate();
    </script>
```

It work on the same page of the "content" div, but not in that way..
i call gmap.js and google maps api in the index.php file

[EDIT]
Here is the ajax code

```
function show_page(category, type)
{
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)    {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari   
     var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
       }   
     else    {
    // code for IE6, IE5   
      var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   
     } 
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  
      {    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
       {   
        if(type != 'search')
        {
            document.getElementById("search_content").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("content").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;   //NELL' ELEMENTO CON QUESTO ID VIENE MOSTRATO IL RISULTATO MANDATO DAL SERVER
    } else
    {
     document.getElementById("content").style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById("search_content").style.display = 'block';  
     document.getElementById("search_content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;   //NELL' ELEMENTO CON QUESTO ID VIENE MOSTRATO IL RISULTATO MANDATO DAL SERVER
    }
    }    
    }  
       xmlhttp.open("GET","show_page_process.php?page="+category+"&type="+type,true); 
       xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So at first I would recommend to use jQuery

Website: http://jquery.com/
Download: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js

And the Code would be like that

```
$.ajax({
  url: "show_map.php",
  context: document.body
}).done(function(data) {
  $("#content").html(data);
});
```

Comment: i forgot to write the ajax code, anyway..it work, because i show also other element. The only problem is the map that is not displayed

Comment: Is there any error in the console of your webbrowser?

Comment: zero error on the index.php, but of course there are an error on the show_map.php page beacuse i call gmap and google maps api in the index and not there.. I tried to call them in show_map.php but nothing change..

Comment: Im not so fluend with normal javascript and ajax. Maybe try my code above just for testing and check it again. Maybe there is something wrong with your ajax. Or try test to send a <script>alert("test");</script> in your show_map.php and try if its triggert in your index

Comment: No change, i've made some search on google..it might be a problem of time? For example the map is loaded before of the 'vision' on the #content div and so is not displayed? (sorry the bad english)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92515/discussion-between-giuseppe-de-paola-and-orgertot).